# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

Some time ago i've installed Visual Studio 2015, then I continue to install 2017.
How can I remove Visual Studio 2015 without affecting to Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Vs from a long time but as far as i remember, each version of VS has is own installer, so you can go to the control panel -> Application and look for the uninstaller of Visual Studio 2015, that should not affect VS2017